# Installing python on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, minikube

I have been trying to install Python in minikube of the below version

```
Linux minikube 4.19.107 #1 SMP Thu May 28 15:07:17 PDT 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However i havent been able to find out a installation package that availabe in this O.S in the minikube.

My objective is to install python on minikube so that i could use ansible from my local machine to deploy things into minikube.Please guide.

Comment: If by deploy things you mean deploying kubernetes objects it would make more sense to see minikube as a kubernetes cluster and configure your host's k8s config to point to the cluster and use kubectl to deploy k8s object to it.

Comment: I wanted to specifically use ansible k8s module to perform a deployment in the minikube. This is the reason am not using kubectl and instead trying to make python work in minikube. Ill edit the question to make this clear . Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to be inside the minikube to deploy to minikube. The deployment via python triggered by ansible can happen from the host.

Comment: Minikube is a Mini Kubernetes Cluster running in your localhost. If you want to deploy something into it, it is done from your localhost. I think having Python installed on your local system is enough for running ansible playbooks (and do whatever needs to be done with your k8s cluster). You don't do Python in Kubernetes. You just tweak some objects (e.g. create a deployment) using its APIs.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my incorrect understanding. I have now been able to point ansible to localhost and deploy into minikube.

Answer (score 3):

Minikube is a dedicated application appliance. It is only for running Kubernetes. You would not install things on it via Ansible. You can use Ansible to automate Kubernetes, but you don't change anything on the host itself, that's just talking to the API.